# Passing isLoading to child Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, components

I have a parent and child component. The parent component calls the API and the results are passed into the child (table). I want to show a loader/spinner inside the table before the rows are loaded.

Is it a good practice if I handle the isLoading on the parent and then pass it to the child as props?

Comment: is this angular

Comment: You should let the parent handle it since the parent is the one calling the api. It would be easier to detect if the api call is done

Comment: Better to do it in the parent component and only after you have the data you can validate it if necessary and then chose to either mout the child view or chose to display an error if so

Answer (score -1):

You can use css transform property

```
<div class="box">

</div>

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.5)
}
```

or check this fiddle for width transition https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/ygn8fk17/7/